# Why is Wordpress failing to connect to MySQL in this docker-compose app?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a docker-compose app that runs **multiple wordpress sites** that share a **single mysql container**.

## Configuration

Here is the corresponding `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  ##################
  # Gateway Server #
  ##################

  #
  #  NOTE:  nginx is included for completenes, but (a priori) not  
  #         relevant to the issue at hand.

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - site0
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  ###################
  # Database Server #
  ###################

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/wpinit.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/wpinit.sql:ro
    env_file:
      - ./mysql/mysql.env  # sets MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

  ###################
  # Wordpress Sites #
  ###################

  site0:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    env_file:
      - ./wordpress/wordpress.env  # contains `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql:3306`
      - ./wordpress/site0/.env  # contains WORDPRESS_DB_(USER|NAME|PASSWORD)
```

Because several wordpress sites will be sharing the `mysql` container, it is no longer feasible to use environment variables to initialize the users/tables/non-root-passwords.  Therefore, I have volume-mounted the following script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`:

```
CREATE DATABASE site0;
CREATE USER 'site0'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecretpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON site0.* TO 'site0'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Symptoms

Running `docker-compose up` produces the following output from `mysql`:

```
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:28.787698Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'site0'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

which is echoed by the `site0` container:

```
site0_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'site0'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
site0_1  |
site0_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'site0'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES) in Standard input code on line 22
```

Further up in the log output, when the mysql init script is called, we get:

```
mysql_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/wpinit.sql
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.094158Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.095076Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.097564Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.097787Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'site0@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.101138Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.102141Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.102677Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'site0 site0@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.103542Z 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.103945Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-12T11:09:25.104155Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
```

## Diagnostics

I first wanted to check that the tables, users and passwords were actually being created in the mysql container:

```
$ docker exec -ti wpsvc_mysql_1 bash
$ mysql -uroot -psupersecretpassword

mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'site0');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'site0') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| site0              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

After double-checking that the database password for `site0` was identical in `./wordpress/site0/.env` and `./mysql/wpinit.sql`, I came scurrying here.

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try `'site0'@'%'` because it's not getting called from the same host.

Comment: As suspected, the issue was simple :)  Thanks for your help!